# Fill blank with value found with XLOOKUP in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

My table looks a little like the below:
[image: table1]

I need to fill the blanks with the following criteria:

- If a field is empty, fill with the value of same country/Yellow/same year
  If Australia/green/2022 is empty, we need the value of Australia/Yellow/2022
- If same country/yellow/same year is empty as well, fill with the value of the region/same color/same year
  If both Australia/green/2022 and Australia/Yellow/2022 are empty, we need the value of Asia/green/2022.
- If that is empty as well, fill with the value of Region/Yellow/same year
  If the previous values are empty, we need the value of Asia/Yellow/2022.

This is what I wrote for the first level (looking for same country/yellow/same year) but can't pinpoint the "results".

```vb
Sub Test()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Sheets("BASIS")

Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long, r As Long, c As Long

LRow = WS.Range("B" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = WS.Cells(LRow, 29)

Dim criteria1, criteria3, search1, search2, search3 As Range
Dim results As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For c = 8 To LCol
    For r = 3 To LRow - 1
        If WS.Cells(r, c) = "" Then
        
            criteria1 = WS.Cells(r, 4)
            criteria3 = WS.Cells(r, 6)
            criteria4 = WS.Cells(2, c)
            
            search1 = WS.Range("D3:D" & LRow)
            search2 = WS.Range("E3:E" & LRow)
            search3 = WS.Range("F3:F" & LRow)
            search4 = WS.Range("H2:AC2")
            
            results = WS.Range("H3:AC" & LRow)
        
            WS.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(criteria1 & "Yellow" & criteria3 & criteria4, search1 & search2 & search3 & search4, results).Value
            'ws.Cells(LRow, c).Value
        End If
    Next r
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Europeans countries -> Europe | 
Asian countries / Australia / New Zealand -> Asia | 
African countries -> Africa | 
South american countries -> South America | 
North american countries -> North America

Comment: Sorry i mean in your example why Asia and not AsiaPacific? Always has to use Asia as base?

Comment: Just took it as an example.

Comment: Just see Australia as "Banana" and Asia as "Fruits". I just need code to get the values, does not matter if it comes from Asia or Asia Pacific, just need an example of right coding. thanks

Comment: You need to add a "region" column.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet for an example does the following.

Get the nearest previous "Yellow" value in the same column for an empty cell.

If no previous value for "Yellow" in the column an error message is generated.

This is the table for testing

[image]

The code:

```
Sub fillexamp()

Dim collect() As Variant

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
j = 0
For i = 3 To lastrow
If Cells(i, 2) = "Yellow" And InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "Asia") <> 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve collect(1, j)
    collect(0, j) = Cells(i, 1)
    collect(1, j) = i
    j = j + 1
End If
Next i
j = j - 1
For cols = 4 To 6
For xrow = 3 To lastrow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(xrow, cols)) Then
replaced = False
For k = j To 0 Step -1
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(collect(1, k), cols)) And collect(1, k) < xrow Then
    Cells(xrow, cols) = Cells(collect(1, k), cols)
    replaced = True
    Exit For
End If
Next k
If Not replaced Then MsgBox "No fill value found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ERROR IN FILL": Exit Sub


End If
Next xrow
Next cols
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for not having been clear in my comments above. I meant we could either take Asia or Asia Pacific for Australia, not any Yellow associated value. For example I cannot take France/Yellow/2022 as a replacement for the missing Australia/Yellow/2022 value.. The code should really look for Region of Country/Yellow/2022.. But in the beginning, we were looking for Australia/Yellow/2022 as Australia/green/2022 was missing... Thank you

Comment: @elisa i added modification. The code was adapted to your sample table what is sorted by (Region/Country) and Yellow is the first row of each.